# Igor Pro HDF5OpenFile keeps showing Browser

Tags: hdf5, igor

I am fairly new to Igor Pro and I am trying to use it to analyze big batch of data files.

My data is wrapped in HDF5-like files with systematic naming. So I would like to write a procedure which would allow me to analyze it without opening the files one by one. I am using the HDF5 package recommended by wavemetrics.

I've spent quite some time reading the doc, and its examples but I can't find a way to open a file without being prompt with a browser to select the file I would like.

So far, here is what I have :

```
Function openDataNXS(filename)
    String filename

    Variable fileID
    string data_name = "data_"+filename
    string actu_name = "actu_"+filename
    HDF5OpenFile /R  fileID as "./"+filename
    if (V_flag == 0) // checks file opening 
        HDF5LoadData /O/N=$data_name fileID, "/scan/scan_data/data_03"// dataset address in the file
        HDF5LoadData /O/N=$actu_name fileID, "/scan/scan_data/actuator_1_1"
        HDF5CloseFile fileID
        display $data_name vs $actu_name
    endif
End
```

Although I provide the function with a filename, I am still prompted with a Browser.
Any Idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide an absolute path to `HDF5OpenFile`. Either via `HDf5OpenFile/PATH=someSymbolicPath fileID as filename` or with filename being an absolute path. If your `./` implies that you mean the location of the experiment try `HDf5OpenFile/PATH=home fileID as filename`.